# How to write constraint with sum of absolutes in Integer Programming?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, linearization, absolute-value

I found a solution for just one term [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398506/linear-programming-absolute-value-greater-than-a-constant)

How can we formulate constraints of the form

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i -a_i| \ge K $$

in Mixed Integer Linear Programming ?

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=linearize+absolute+value+

Comment: None of those actually help, since the abs in those occurs in the objective which is minimized. Here one a needs a small epsilon approach to prevent one term from growing larger then abs and thereby fulfilling the inequality when it should no be fullfilled.

Comment: Here is a very explicit reference. https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mipform/dhtml/chap2s1.html?scroll=ssecabsval  Then sum of the y's >= R

Comment: That one works. Did big M over small epsilon. Neat. Do you wanna write up an answer post?

Comment: Not really. That's why I wrote a comment. Have at it.  Actually needs to be modified a bit to introduce a lower bound which might not be 0 as was assumed in the link.

Answer (score 1):

In CPLEX you can use the absolute value.
For instance with the OPL API you can write

```
int n=5;
range r=1..n;

int K=10;

int a[i in r]=i;
dvar int x[r];

subject to
{
  sum (i in r) abs(x[i]-a[i])>=K;
}
```